# Another word for hitting another person's hip with our hip romantically

Tags: single-word-requests

Generally we hit our friends or loved ones with our hip on their side of the hip while walking aside them romantically.i need a word or phrase for it.
and need a phrase or word for when We hit with our shoulder against other's shoulder accidentally or purposely like how we see in movies hero n heroine dash with each other and books falls down kind of.

Comment: In hockey, this is known as a "hip-check"—although it is rarely done romantically.

Comment: When my wife observes this action when watching Hallmark movies, she calls them **bumps**. They happen at least one in every movie.